# Get websiteId from observer event

Tags: php, magento, events

Given that I have multiple websites in my Magento instance, how do I identify the website where a particular event happened? For example, observing the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event lets me catch all Add to Cart events. Let's say I wanted to get the website Id of the website where this Add to Cart event happened, how do you I do that?

```
public function addToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $websiteId = $observer->getEvent()->get ??? ();
}
```

I know that I can get the `websiteIds` of the product that was added to the cart, by doing the following

```
$websiteIds = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getWebsiteIds();
```

But that is not what I want, because if the product belongs to more than one website, it will give me all the websites and not the one where the Add to Cart event happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
```

within your observer? That should give you the current store id..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the StoreId from Mage, not from the observer object.

**StoreId:**
`Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();`

**WebsiteId:**
`Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();`